# Callback is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, callback

I have two callbacks that aren't working in my model. They don't raises any error messages either.

The first callback is: `after_update :state_closed` and I want to use this to close the ticket when I select ticket state from the view 'solved' or 'canceled'. So, I want it in this case is to be closed

The second callback is `after_create :assign_state` and I want to use this to say the ticket is assigned or its not assigned so if the employee_id is blank thats mean the ticket is not assigned to any employee yet. If employee_id is not black so this ticket is assigned

Here is my ticket.rb

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :default_values
  after_update :state_closed
  after_create :assign_state

  attr_accessible :description, :title, :employee_department_id, :user_id, :first_name,
:last_name , :email, :state_id, :employee_id, :ticket_state, :assign_state


  belongs_to :employee_department
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :employee

  has_many :replies

  def default_values
    self.state_id = 3 if self.state_id.nil?
  end

  def to_label
    ticket_state.to_s
  end

  def state_closed
    if self.ticket_state == "Solved" || self.ticket_state == "Canceled"
      self.ticket_state = "Closed"
      self.save
    end
  end

  def assign_state
    if self.employee_id.nil?
      self.assign_state = "Un-assigned"
    else
      self.assign_state = "Assigned"
    end
  end

  Ticket.all.each do |ticket|
    if ticket.ticket_state.blank?
      ticket.ticket_state = 'open'
    end
    ticket.save
  end
  ...
```

This is from server logs when i choose "solved" for example it is updated to "solved" if my callbacks are working then in this case it should change from solved to closed but that's not happening

```
Started PUT "/tickets/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-14 21:46:54 +0200
Processing by TicketsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LZRTSjq9EWqgG6ub3xpd7fioWNtY1SSzy5XQA8ZNep0=", "ticket"=>{"ticket_state"=>"solved"}, "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  State Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "states".* FROM "states" 
  Ticket Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets" WHERE "tickets"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  UPDATE "tickets" SET "ticket_state" = 'solved', "updated_at" = '2013-09-14 19:46:54.926307' WHERE "tickets"."id" = 1
   (95.2ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/tickets
Completed 302 Found in 100ms (ActiveRecord: 96.0ms)
```

Comment: first check if the those two methods are being called or not

Comment: And you can write some messages to the console from within the methods, to check if they're getting hit... Also, you could put a bang on the end of save temporarily which will throw a more noticeable error if the ticket isn't saving successfully.

Comment: Also, use self.update_column(:ticket_state, "Closed") to avoid triggering the after update callback again when you save within the callback method. Update_column doesn't trigger validations or callbacks: save does.

Comment: Why use an `after_save` for `state_closed`? Why not use one of the before hooks? Similarly for `assign_state`. Also, why the capitalization difference between the `'open'` and `'Closed'` states and why aren't you validating `ticket_state` to make sure that it only contains allowed values?

Comment: @muistooshort its after_update not after_save for state_closed and even after_save both not working. and for the difference between open and Closed i guess thats not the problem now, the problem is the callbacks not called like they are not there.

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh its seems they are not called but i don't know why.

Comment: @snowangel i added self.update(:ticket_state, "Closed") instead of self.ticket_state = "Closed" but nothing happend

Comment: Question updated i have added the log of updating to solved

Comment: You're missing the point, why are you using after callbacks for these things at all? You should probably be using `before_validation` callbacks to adjust things and then validations to ensure that everything makes sense.

Comment: I think the problem is not in the callback but the comparison. Make sure you need compare "Solved" instead of "solved".

Comment: @cortex what about the second callback for :assign_state. i made it 'un-assign" and "assign" but how can i make it work for the current created tickets and the tickets will be created ?

Comment: I think your question was solved... justo call `save`.

Comment: @cortex also i have changed to `after_commit :state_closed` and `before_save :assign_state`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues with each are as follows:

`state_closed` is not being called because of capitalization issue: "solved" does not equal "Solved". Change the capitalizations to match, or compare the strings when they're both downcased.

`assign_state` is probably being called, but not persisting because you never actually save the model once it's changed.  Try saving after you update on create.

Comment: is there a way to make `assign_state` runs for the current tickets and new tickets which will be created ?

Comment: Sure, you could use a callback with `on: :create` to make sure it's being set.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#on.  Or you could just use `before_create` instead of `after_create`.

Comment: and what about the current created , will be on update only ?

Comment: No, you will need to run a rake task or some commands in the console to change the existing records. This is probably easier than trying to do it through your application code.